# node.js - synchronos event listeners

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

In my javascript script I'm forced to use the EventEmitter and split the problem into two functions.

Is there any way to make a synchronos event listener? So the script would wait until the the event was triggered.

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
var emitter = new EventEmmitter();

function bar(arg) {
  //calculations and stuff
  emitter.emit('done', result);
}

function foo(arg) {
  bar(arg);
  emitter.on('done', (result) => {
    return result; //this return statement doesn't work for foo()
  });

  //the code here should be processed after the event above was triggered.
  //here should be a return statement for the result 

}

console.log(foo("something")); //or process the result otherwise
```

Comment: Why not put the code instide the 'done' callback?

Comment: Because I can't put a return statement for foo() into an anonymous function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning a value of a function with Promise object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725584/returning-a-value-of-a-function-with-promise-object)

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what you are trying to do and what your problem set is.  I think that you are misunderstanding the intention behind the event loop and event listeners in general.

Comment: @zero298 event listeners and event loop have nothing in common, `emit()` synchronously calls listeners. But I agree that the code is not idiomatic and it would be better to use callback-based approach

Comment: bar() is a function to calculate a xxHash of a file asynchronously by using fs.createReadStream(). The hash is getting emitted. foo() compares the hash with a previous calculated hash und returns if the content of the file has changed.

Comment: @phyyyl well, then you just cannot. It is impossible to wait synchronously for the result of asynchronous function. You should either rewrite `foo()` to be asynchronous or `bar()` to be synchronous